# corrupted response reader, expected non null value for __typename

Tags: android, graphql, apollo-client

I am making a graphQL query but got response with failure. The weird thing is that in my query I don't have field that's fails on null. Could you please give me any direction is it problem with the model or is it server problem

[image]

Comment: Each type should have a __typename field, as it's mandatory per GQL spec. There's a similar issue on GitHub that has some steps you can use to verify this has been set up properly on the back-end (or how to workaround this using the front-end): https://github.com/apollographql/apollo-kotlin/issues/3044